# Beautifulsoup4. Как получить значение (text) дочернего тэга?

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4

Всем привет. Использую `beautifulsoup4`. Есть `div.parent`, в котором есть 8 `div.child`. Как получить текст (в примере получить цифры) каждого `div.child` именно в `div.parent`?

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
  <div class="child">5</div>
  <div class="child">6</div>
  <div class="child">7</div>
  <div class="child">8</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Первый вариант через `select`, по моему, самый удобный и нормальный:

```
html = """\
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
  <div class="child">5</div>
  <div class="child">6</div>
  <div class="child">7</div>
  <div class="child">8</div>
</div>
"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
root = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

nums = [el.text for el in root.select('.parent > div')]
print(nums)

nums = [el.strip() for el in root.select_one('.parent').text.split('\n') if el.strip()]
print(nums)

nums = [el.text for el in root.find(attrs={'class': 'parent'}).find_all('div')]
print(nums)
```

Консоль:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']
```

---

У первого варианта (который работает с css-селекторами) могут быть разные варианты описания запроса. Добавлю к тому что уже есть:

```
nums = [el.text for el in root.select('.parent > .child')]
print(nums)

nums = [el.text for el in root.select('div > div')]
print(nums)

nums = [el.text for el in root.select('div.parent > div')]
print(nums)

nums = [el.text for el in root.select('div.parent > div.child')]
print(nums)
```

Comment: Мне понравился ваш вариант с `root.find(...).find_all(...)`. Я бы его еще немного "улучшил": `nums = list(map(operator.attrgetter('text'), root.find(attrs={'class':'parent'}).find_all('div')))`

Comment: @MaxU, мне больше нравятся генераторы использовать, чем функциональный стиль (по крайней мере для данного примера). А select я рекомендую из-за того что это подтянет знания css-селекторов и поиск через select более компактный

Comment: Большое спасибо:)

Comment: @gil9red, а можно в select указать несколько родителей? Типа 'div.one > div.two > div.three' ?

Comment: @bytesmite, можно, но обычно это не требуется

Comment: @gil9red, ты меня сильно выручил, спасибо тебе огромное человеческое :)